# How do I store guest checkouts?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Ok, so my site is just like "Post Your Order" rather than the usual online payment method since I will be shipping the item first then the cash which is the Cash On Delivery offered by Shipping services here.

I have a users table which have
user_id, email, password, first and last name, etc.

an user_order table which have
order_id, user_id_fk, order_status, order_placed, address_id_fk

an order_items table which have
order_item_id, order_id_fk, product_id, quantity, size_id_fk

address table
address_id, user_id_fk, street, city, province, etc

So, if the user is registered it's easy to do this since i would just link their user_id to the user_order table and the address from their address_book

My problem is, how do i do that with guest checkouts? I'm trying to avoid them to be forced to register even though it's easy.

What on my mind right now is to just insert them to the users table too, but with their password as NULL and just make a guest group and put them to that group.

But that may cause a problem, email in my users table must be unique, guest checkouts may happen more than once from the same email soo... now what?

should i just add column to the orders table? another, name, email, address? so it's not tied to the users? that's possible but there's a feature i would like the registered user to have... to track their Order History.

Help please... Thanks :D ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with "Drew Pierce" but from other side to give you another option

**first** you should read about eCommerce platform (for example OpenCart), how they drive this stuff.

**second** you don't need to add the each guest to the user table for the following:

**1-** guest does not have any right to see the history of orders or ... etc

**2-** email field must be mandatory in checkout and there is notification email will send to him also (maybe you add confirmation email.. up to you).

**3-** all what you need to save in your DB is the order details in the order table

**4-** all the process between you and the guest will be via his email

**5-** he do not have right to track any order or see his activities till he become a real user

**6-** order details must always has the all detail about the user even if he is real user (it will be duplicated data for real user but the user can change his email or phone number in any time, where he can not do it for the old order ,, so you always know the real history of the orders)

**7-** in the user table, there is only one guest user but in the order table there are many orders and each order has its details, email, phone number ,,, etc

Comment: But i as an admin would also like to track all the orders including their details. This is one the reason that makes it complicated

Comment: And also i need their details so i would know where and to whom i would ship it

Comment: 6.... the number 6... that's it! i'll try that one! I just thought that it would be redundant. Thanks! Finally, someone has confirmed my doubts! Thanks!

Comment: yes all this details that you want are in the order details .. you can track and know the shipping destination from the order details

Comment: this is not cross talk. i am happy for no points trust me. typically in a normalized data structure (would love to look at proposed schema if you need help). but typically address is not saved in order detail. order is the order (#,date, cust/user_id, ship addr_id,high level), order_detail is line_items (where some can be back ordered, so for each line item you have ordered and shipped qty). if you have multiple shipments against an order you can have multiple order shipping info with tracking info (pk id, order #, tracking #). all that gets fleshed out when talking about a schema. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

the main thing is getting their money. if they want to remain a guest let them. remind them that only users registered can receive promotions and see prior activity. prior activity while not a registered user WILL NOT be seen later.

let's say they have 10 orders from that email address. so what, put them in as new users **each** time and plop their email addr in there. flag that user as a guest.  so 10 new guest type users for grandma@blahblah.com. No email goes out. afterall, people could be spoofing the system using some poor grandma's email addr.

now they want to be a registered user. email is sent and they have to click on it to become a user (link in email).

now that 11th purchase is from a registered user (grandma@blahblah.com). Order history: 1 order.

seems strait forward to me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that's what I've been thinking too, I'll just try it. I'll just come back if any failure is found

Comment: i have often wanted to order something without the hassle of registering. i am late to get out the door or don't want the email (a confirmation order # would be nice :>)  so i don't place the order cuz i just want to get it and move on. if i can't i split

Comment: Ok now i found the problem with this, when registering the system looks for the email, if it's there it means it's in use and would show an error that it's already in use

Answer (score 1):

For usability reasons, you might actually *want* users to be able to see past orders placed with their e-mail address. The billing e-mail field answers the question "whom do you authorize to view this order?". This way, `grandma@blahblah.com` can place several orders, and then once she actually registers (by changing her password), the past orders placed as a guest will be there for her to track. So try this flow, sometimes called the [shadow profile](http://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/what-exactly-is-a-facebook-shadow-profile/) pattern:

1. Word your guest checkout page to make it clear that the rightful owner of the billing e-mail address will be able to see all orders placed on the site using that address.
2. If the address doesn't exist in your `users` table, create the account with a zeroed password hash and a null `confirmed_on` date.
3. This step changes based on whether you want guests to be able to use e-mail addresses of registered users.

   - If so, add an `is_guest` column to `user_order`.
   - If not, and if `confirmed_on` is not null, require the user to log in. This means all orders prior to `confirmed_on` are guest orders, and all orders afterward are logged-in orders.
4. Send the guest an e-mail receipt containing a password reset link. Make sure this goes out with correct SPF and DKIM records. Label the link with something like this:

   > Sign up to manage your orders with $store_name.
   >
   > In rare cases, you may be listed as the billing contact for an order that you did not place. If so, follow this link to cancel the order.
5. When the user first follows an e-mailed password reset link, set the `confirmed_on` date.
6. In the logged-in user's order history report, clearly mark each order as guest or registered.

If someone who is not `grandma@blahblah.com` enters `grandma@blahblah.com` on a guest order, the real owner of `grandma@blahblah.com` would get the e-mail receipt and thus a chance to cancel it.

The other way is to associate orders to sessions rather than users. You're probably already making a random session ID (and storing it in a cookie) to distinguish a guest's cart from another guest's cart. So change the `user_id_fk` in your `user_order` table to a `session_id_fk`. Then link session IDs to user IDs in whatever `user_session` table you're already using.

Comment: here is the problem as i see it. grandma@blah places an order. she has to have it. no grandma@blah in system. in a rush, technology confuses her. not registered. several other orders are placed afterwards as grandma@blah. perhaps it is grandma, or maybe it's TheBigBad wolf. then the real grandma@blah sits down with grandpa to order some more candles after they 'register.' grandpa say, "what are these orders for sex toys?". Since there is no separation or knowing who is who, you are screwed. Excuse the punn

Comment: as for sessions, grandma says where is my browser, oh here it is, this Fox thing, or is it that IE thing (or maybe on another computer or daughter's house). different cookie info.

Comment: @DrewPierce Grandma would get the e-mail receipt from the wolf's first order and thus a chance to sign up and cancel it. I've expanded the suggested wording to account for this.

Comment: it sits in her Junk folder. doesn't do anything about order history. it is like someone as a guest, wanting to be a guest, just slapping any old email in there. their credit card gets charged. just saying these are all bandaids on a poorly designed system. What would anyone think if they got that email in peach/pink above? I would say "they are clueless"

Comment: @DrewPierce Updated again with a better "band-aid" addressing missing e-mail receipts. Now grandma can tell grandpa "The `Guest` orders aren't me" and proves it by showing shipping addresses.

Comment: gonna vote for you out of principle of effort !  Thing is grandma can't cancel the order, it is already bouncing down the road in an orange and purple FedEx truck. Plus she is offended at the 5 emails, will never buy there again, and suffers a divorce !  But you got my plus vote

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing as you thought, just add the user and add a column `'guests' int(1)` where if the user is a guest, this value is set to `1` and if not, `0`.

Then just set the password to an empty string too.

Comment: Look on the comment i posted at @Drew Pierce. I would have issues with the email not unique when someone finally decide to register that email